# Как просматривать офис файлы на офлайн сайте

Tags: javascript, php, css, html5, excel

В фирме есть локальный сайт приложение для хранения файлов, задача просматривать файлы excel word в браузере.

Суть в том что доступа к интернету нет так что вариант типа Google docs не работает. Есть какие нибудь идеи?

Comment: Идей нет и не будет, пока вы не опишите задачу и окружение более подробно. Что за приложение? Как хранятся? Что за формат файлов? Почему в браузере нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Приложение просто выводит таблицу с  именами файлов из папки на сервере, в которой есть ссылка на страницу просмотра. В которой в свою очередь iframe ссылающийся на этот файл. Фрэмом можно открыть только txt и pdf. А интересует можно ли каким то образом просматривать файлы xls xlsx doc docx